# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, transactions

I am trying to work with spring 4 , hiberate 4 to develop a rest app and getting following error with BeanDefinitionStoreException.

I have changed classes from hibernate3 to hibernate4, eventhough I am getting following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected
```

exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-
   servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:643)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:657)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

library files

My Dispatcher-servlet file:

I have gone through some posts to solve org.xml.sax.SAXParseException,
 I have included beans with beans:beans and even mentioned in xsi:schemaLocation

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-        
beans-4.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-
context.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-
4.0.xsd ">

<annotation-driven/>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</beans:bean> 

<context:component-scan base-package="net.javaonline.spring.restful" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" /> 



<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/SCM1" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="postgres123"/>
</beans:bean> 

 <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners"> false</beans:prop> 
              <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql"> false   </beans:prop> 

        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" >
     <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
 </beans:beans>




<pre> Here following are the library files<pre>
 lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
 lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
 lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
 lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
 lib/hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar
 lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
 lib/jackson-annotations-2.5.4.jar
 lib/jackson-core-2.2.0.jar
 lib/jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar
 lib/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
 lib/jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
 lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
 lib/jstl-1.2.jar
 lib/spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
 lib/spring-aspects-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
 lib/spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
 lib/spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
 lib/spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
 lib/spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
 lib/spring-framework-bom-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
 lib/spring-jdbc-2.0.6.jar
 spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
 lib/spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
 lib/spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
 lib/spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: The error is clear: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. You are missing the dependency for `TransactionInterceptor`.

Comment: @alfcope I have spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar  in lib, isn't it enough?

Comment: Show your pom and your configuration please, the way you are creating your transaction manager.

Comment: @alfcope, I have edited my post, included configuration and libraryfiles. I am very new to do this, please don't hesitate. I am grateful for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Hibernate 4 but when creating your beans you are trying to use hibernate3 classes.

In your xml configuration change any reference from hibernate3 to hibernate4. For example when creating the factory and the transaction manager.

```
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.
  AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
....
</beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" 
 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.
 HibernateTransactionManager" >
     <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
```

Add a dependency to the libray aopalliance.jar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
    <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have changed my code according to your suggestion, but this time I am getting this org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 17 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans:beans'.        But as my configuration file I have mentioned beans

Comment: Update your question and add your rest-servlet.xml, please.

Comment: Why `beans-4.0.xsd` is in a new line? I think you have a not visible character there. Try with `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd` everything together, on the same line.

Comment: this solved org.xml.sax.SAXParseException exception, but I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor
exception, even I have added all the jars.

Comment: Add a dependency to aopalliance.jar. I have updated my answer.

Comment: many thanks, this worked as charm when I changed org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean to org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean